# Folium Timestampedgeojson - How to add dynamic html for the title of the map

Tags: python, visualization, geospatial, folium, folium-plugins

I wanted to know if it is possible to add dynamic html to a folium map using timestampedgeojson so that the title of the map can get updated on every frame (.e.g. Date). When the visualization starts the title of the map will get updated with the new date on each frame, when it is being played.

I am following this example below that constructs a basic time-based visualization.

```
m = folium.Map(location=[35.68159659061569, 139.76451516151428], zoom_start=16)

# Lon, Lat order.
lines = [
    {
        "coordinates": [
            [139.76451516151428, 35.68159659061569],
            [139.75964426994324, 35.682590062684206],
        ],
        "dates": ["2017-06-02T00:00:00", "2017-06-02T00:10:00"],
        "color": "red",
    },
    {
        "coordinates": [
            [139.75964426994324, 35.682590062684206],
            [139.7575843334198, 35.679505030038506],
        ],
        "dates": ["2017-06-02T00:10:00", "2017-06-02T00:20:00"],
        "color": "blue",
    },
    {
        "coordinates": [
            [139.7575843334198, 35.679505030038506],
            [139.76337790489197, 35.678040905014065],
        ],
        "dates": ["2017-06-02T00:20:00", "2017-06-02T00:30:00"],
        "color": "green",
        "weight": 15,
    },
    {
        "coordinates": [
            [139.76337790489197, 35.678040905014065],
            [139.76451516151428, 35.68159659061569],
        ],
        "dates": ["2017-06-02T00:30:00", "2017-06-02T00:40:00"],
        "color": "#FFFFFF",
    },
]

features = [
    {
        "type": "Feature",
        "geometry": {
            "type": "LineString",
            "coordinates": line["coordinates"],
        },
        "properties": {
            "times": line["dates"],
            "style": {
                "color": line["color"],
                "weight": line["weight"] if "weight" in line else 5,
            },
        },
    }
    for line in lines
]

folium.plugins.TimestampedGeoJson(
    {
        "type": "FeatureCollection",
        "features": features,
    },
    period="PT1M",
    add_last_point=True,
).add_to(m)

m
```